# Scrape table data from .jsp page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table from .jsp page (details below).
The table loads only after entering data (Train Number & Journey station)

For your trials, Train number can be **56913** & Journey station can be **SBC** (This will automatically change to 'KSR Bengaluru" after the data is entered.

With the script below, i am able to generate the table, however, i am unable to extract it (print results in an empty list). I need to get the full table. Can anyone help with letting be know how to extract the table?

I am very new to web-scraping. Hence, if have made some basic mistake, please nudge me gently in the right direction.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import soupsieve as sv
import requests
# Activate the following line if you do not want to see the Firefox window.
# Better deactivate it for debugging.
# os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'

url = 'https://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/trainOnMapBh.jsp'

opts = Options()
driver = Firefox(firefox_binary=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", options=opts)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

train_field = driver.find_element_by_id("trnSrchTxt")
train_field.send_keys("56913")
time.sleep(2)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('SBC',Keys.ENTER)
actions.perform()

WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
result_table = driver.find_elements_by_id("mapTrnSch")
print(result_table)
```

**Update**
Apart from the answer from @MadRay, the following code gets the data as well (not sure how robust it is).

```
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re

os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
opts = Options()
driver = Firefox(firefox_binary=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", options=opts)
driver.get('https://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/trainOnMapBh.jsp')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

train_field = driver.find_element_by_id("trnSrchTxt")
train_field.send_keys("11302")
time.sleep(2)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('SBC',Keys.ENTER)
actions.perform()
time.sleep(2)
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
table_rows =soup.find_all('table')[3].find_all('tr')
rows=[]
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    rows.append([i.text for i in td])
delaydata = rows[3:]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(delaydata, columns = ['StopNo','Station',1,'SchArr','SchDep','ETA_ATA','Arr_Delay','ETD_ATD','DepDelay','Distance','PF'])
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to search results by class_name, not an id:

`results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mapTrnSch")`

All other code is working well.

*Important notice*. You'll have two results. First is for table headers, second for table content.

Here's example I have written without WebDriverWait and ActionChains:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/trainOnMapBh.jsp'

driver = Firefox(firefox_binary=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", options=opts)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

# Send search data
driver.find_element_by_id("trnSrchTxt").send_keys("56913")  # Train
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("jrnyStn").send_keys('SBC')  # Journey
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("searchTrainInMapBtn").click()  # Submit button (seems like we do not need to click on it, but let's click for sure)
time.sleep(5)

# Gain results
results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mapTrnSch")
print(results[0].text)  # 1st result for table headers
print(results[1].text)  # 2st result for table content
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I get the result i expected with your answer. I had already figured out an alternative way to get the data & turn it into a dataframe. If you have time, can you have a look at that code & let me know if there are any pitfalls with that (in case we change the train number of if i want get data for more trains in a loop or something like that).  I have updated my code in the question.