# Beautiful Soup returning 'None' - python - am I using wrong HTML info?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am just starting with `beautifulsoup` and I am trying to scrape the number of points to buy a ticket from jetblues website. What is wrong with the "job" portion of this code that makes it return a `None` value (which I know from another post on here causes my finding_point to return an attribute error).

Here is jetblues link:

- https://www.jetblue.com/booking/flights?from=JFK&to=LAX&depart=2023-01-16&isMultiCity=false&noOfRoute=1&lang=en&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&sharedMarket=false&roundTripFaresFlag=false&usePoints=true

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


html_text = requests.get('https://www.jetblue.com/booking/flights?from=JFK&to=LAX&depart=2023-01-16&isMultiCity=false&no''OfRoute=1&lang=en&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&sharedMarket=false&roundTripFaresFlag=false&usePoints=true').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

#\/ meant to find the box which the points are located on (the only box that repeats)
job = soup.find('jb-flight-detail-item', class_='ng-tns-c230-2 ng-star-inserted')

# finds point values of the flight
finding_point = job.find('span', class_='pointsText ng-star-inserted').text

print(finding_point)
```
````

Comment: The website you are trying to scrape is protected and loads the content via javascript. The solution would be to scrape it with [Pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer).

Comment: @era-net There's a way to do it without Pypeter, see the below answer.

Comment: Clean response in json. well done @MendelG!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I just posted an in-depth answer to a similar problem - see [Scrape table from JSP website using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74947339/12349734)* for how I got the correct URL.

The data is loaded *dynamically* via sending a `POST` request to:

```
https://jbrest.jetblue.com/lfs-rwb/outboundLFS
```

You can get the data as a Python dictionary - `dict` and acess the keys/values

```py
import requests
from pprint import pprint

headers = {
    "authority": "jbrest.jetblue.com",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "api-version": "v3",
    "application-channel": "Mobile_Web_iOS",
    "booking-application-type": "NGB",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "origin": "https://www.jetblue.com",
    "referer": "https://www.jetblue.com/booking/flights?from=JFK&to=LAX&depart=2023-01-16&isMultiCity=false&no%27%27OfRoute=1&lang=en&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&sharedMarket=false&roundTripFaresFlag=false&usePoints=true",
    "sec-ch-ua": '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "x-1itxwo9i-a": "dGhy3R_YbQU=D3LlOuILANzSj4OqMmmzQnGFfhMsMXf6rNWBWYazb7EzSRjHiVDBIZ6N3IQySS0=i4BI5xXLTVwC-FGteH4u7h97MXYojHOk--wXzg2yNwqnZNI9PNUm3tm9J6xpsQEYXpoo5g-B6rm_FaWEqS2ggvKlC_AUVnRrhnCc_n11Cez6JT=3R9LDu3TUFcLwm3ZFobQO6vPAlohbJz-=lJMLFORNYyGGI6NSd=BZP100dCpSI6AI0NkA_U-hDfNzTzZseCTs6RWoZ5NXFLULCq=oPi7oLMAUkeVeGBl-yikgc3caomprAKgGxKJ9MfN9tbX6aMrZEDh4ssHhbYNF9jsSv52bJEO5gPQE3kzwGQzZR_sOc0RMsMeSU230z9CBRYGEEv4jKK1vq2bicH7f_MsZM54Ez1ioSVV4dTX-gdFeZV6SE-ZdUrkQBMtJsU=rxlSrNjUAdqZcZ03xO9wgurv=Q4i5Jy7TjUj-i=gATdJxH2=Z_Aag2vPQ2Uv1QZQ0-OJ9ee_jEZ-XucZXwCW=TpOk9hYrOpct3JvEd6EaW4VwAL3QL2lAPpqH1EwPzwiP1nP_nmdCktx=s5cQAM=3uijR6BHYp0Bw9oGmae0C1Xu=donAKxItecD7KLyoonlBiEjjE96it9M1epW0aHepT-qFFPvxYxSXLbClPazCal7bJs0-oZV_7Nhi0RHPLsJB7UEeoJU1_PUfEsM5kMLBb4H7mU9FJB_u6XYlCNjRZZtWB_gdpByoxSsZz-cqBoke46SeIAc4ZP-B=nmj2WtqEq9fQVaMYs3edUiv4V0rC65VoaDlpB15ypesMsS9sF2glhwKar0b3UvVvH2puihCbSlgjpC-3DC5Z5F_b5jeblVw6oK2QxygUfDZweOG-YAHjfvGLLYTrkbSHMWyI5k6lwtBFBFxIuWPIW2UtTM-UhtBfXOFbg=FY-hSvgXLfASSeL6SS_d9pdctku11jsIptV_7=b=KekwOFtXnIbrqWGHvr9=CWS--XMOwxQAdVFpmcseahiaxrOLG0WESbM5Eq49335fcD0ywfORIyHjB2gZIw7uBrI_INyxJDjYw0p5VHNtXi7MkU9gtMtl=6L5aPUPdJ_ZsQvBswSAFQHmquY=HuDo3dIEITH_WMDftFjHVwH6iYnJvd_mR9=aLsk3FEbvBejTMEk4NMGJqUThOO5_C6cxmDQ_ZOd-hTtwVwJ=WESdnqz9rthoWcnyMZouWdLvW1kTf-lpd9flbwDGRQy=FH3m03K4KJlgOZizeVT7sYHibkXyc6aywQGU91_IjiLcJx=au0FIdqwSs2-S9REIncdu2ENt0hSh6E3vOrwLsXrYks__ul9CR7b-snuk515MWjwIOKvzIhBq_2e10B034fYExdWI2j0YOvzseEIetqlfS1raUqsQwT0TnHvg725LO9z-eAYGI1q9=tOTEpGffj1i=x5DBDZSrfpcmoEc16CoG6bSJfC6FaIaJrs0c64QZrXCuDHhk4QNcq6VdRpeTWS9Z6KB9q4wqPJ-rNKXSY4x3Nx-wOS5hydVp95zyugv_9lpcro7ZAxvjXhBWM21FTHp3Zg7HGN2p-99CU5ezUj7ItMIpUdorqzTh3Z4__PhFw2=55yzOJVL_kOt2Q7fsVHt2ZHwuSkgdUVIb9Nv1m5yuwoo_CU4Rdf97ZblRbm7bx5jLICC_dmoFzWdX3tGxSqMW17c2QXPaX1zYUIktkIcwhDAnfc-24nU_PJT6k1A3Ob7aPVSePvwHM7gD=E42xrbAVt=nXXBuBZ2s4DdpS_-9MA3seYJrvAIev9oFZtTWHbVRXGClu9o65wozfDlF=u61Axx1UJXR6Sh",
    "x-1itxwo9i-b": "-45yhia",
    "x-1itxwo9i-c": "AOAcxVyFAQAADXFrdOVEXoQI7zTN5iQ1lLNcvkiu305HtVFOQGyYYf2UUG-D",
    "x-1itxwo9i-d": "ABaChIjBDKGNgUGAQZIQhISi0eIApJmBDgBsmGH9lFBvgwAAAAAfd583AEbEYf3IACcWKPxzLLkRBrA",
    "x-1itxwo9i-f": "A_w5xlyFAQAAlccodlToue9smz72CmbMQ-QQejmvZyA3GjnqJS3FcKKLsGi7AS07OviucgBSwH8AAOfvAAAAAA==",
    "x-1itxwo9i-z": "q",
    "x-b3-spanid": "1672298774046",
    "x-b3-traceid": "332f7d010c4d9180",
}

data = '{"tripType":"oneWay","from":"JFK","to":"LAX","depart":"2023-01-16","cabin":"economy","refundable":false,"dates":{"before":"3","after":"3"},"pax":{"ADT":1,"CHD":0,"INF":0,"UNN":0},"redempoint":true,"pointsBreakup":{"option":"","value":0},"isMultiCity":false}'


response = requests.post(
    "https://jbrest.jetblue.com/lfs-rwb/outboundLFS", headers=headers, data=data
)


pprint(response.json())
```

Prints (truncated):

```
{'countryCode': 'US',
 'currency': 'USD',
 'dategroup': [{'from': 'JFK',
                'group': [{'date': '2023-01-13T00:00:00-05:00',
                           'fareTax': '5.60',
                           'points': '18400',
                           'uri': '/air/lfs/63ad42b425eabf0ffa0ccc26/origins-destinations/1/departure-dates/2023-01-13'},
                          {'date': '2023-01-14T00:00:00-05:00',
                           'fareTax': '5.60',
                           'points': '18400',
                           'uri': '/air/lfs/63ad42b425eabf0ffa0ccc26/origins-destinations/1/departure-dates/2023-01-14'},
                          {'date': '2023-01-15T00:00:00-05:00',
                           'fareTax': '5.60',
                           'points': '18400',
                           'uri': '/air/lfs/63ad42b425eabf0ffa0ccc26/origins-destinations/1/departure-dates/2023-01-15'},
                          {'date': '2023-01-16T00:00:00-05:00',
                           'fareTax': '5.60',
                           'points': '17500',
                           'uri': '/air/lfs/63ad42b425eabf0ffa0ccc26/origins-destinations/1/departure-dates/2023-01-16'},
                          {'date': '2023-01-17T00:00:00-05:00',
```