# Correctly refer to a button to scrape aspx webpage using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract data from an aspx site.  Trying to find the name of the submit button to include in the post request, but it doesn't appear when I inspect the page.

```
import csv
import requests

form_data = {
    'CalendarioDesde': '01/11/2022',
    'CalendarioHasta': '28/12/2022',
    'IdEstacion': 'Aeropuerto San Luis (REM)',
    '': 'Consultar'   # trying to get the button name
}

response = requests.post('http://clima.edu.ar/InformePorPeriodo.aspx', data=form_data)

reader = csv.reader(response.text.splitlines())
```

Based on the posts I've seen, it's standard to use beautiful soup for scraping aspx pages, but I wasn't able to find a tutorial on the complex parameters (i.e. VIEWSTATE).  So I'm starting with this basic requests version.

If this isn't the correct method, please suggest a post / resource that I can use as a template to extract data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yesterday, I answered a question on how to get data loaded dynamically. See:
[Scrape table from JSP website using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74947339/scrape-table-from-jsp-website-using-python)*

To get the CSV data you can try:

```py
import requests
import csv


params = {
    'tipo': 'Periodo',
    'Estacion': '42',
    'fechaDesde': '20221101', # --> Same as 2022-11-01
    'fechahasta': '20221229', #  Same as  2022/12/29
}

response = requests.get('http://clima.edu.ar/ObtenerCsv.aspx', params=params)

reader = csv.reader(response.text.splitlines())
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Prints (Truncated):

```
['Fecha/Hora;"Precipitacion (mm)";"Temperatura (ºC)";"Humedad (%)";"Dir. Del Viento (º)";"Int. del Viento (m/s)";"Radiación (w/m2)"']
['29/12/2022 20:00:00;0', '00;28', '20;16', '80;128', '60;0', '20;11', '70']
['29/12/2022 19:00:00;0', '00;32', '40;11', '10;194', '20;0', '40;181', '50']
['29/12/2022 18:00:00;0', '00;33', '00;10', '70;228', '00;1', '40;413', '60']
['29/12/2022 17:00:00;0', '00;33', '40;10', '50;223', '70;2', '20;647', '60']
['29/12/2022 16:00:00;0', '00;33', '30;10', '90;235', '40;2', '70;841', '00']
```

---

You can inspect your browser's Network calls to view the requests by pressing the <kbd>F12</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: Really helpful.  In Firefox the only way I see that is to go to the network tab.  The output isn't as elegant as what you showed

Comment: @matsuo_basho I'm on Chrome

Comment: Great!  If straightforward, how would I also add the name of the station to the output?

Comment: Also, just noticed that the output looks odd - it's not splitting the columns in the correct place.

Comment: I see csv reader just needs a delimiter specified, since data is in Euro format with commas for decimals, and semicolons for delimiters.